# Android Studio Error:(117, 29) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add many colors in arrayList and set them as pie chatrs data.
but
This line
`pieDataSet.setColor(colors);`
gives me

```
Error:(117, 29) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to int
```

this error.

This is the code

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors =new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS){
        colors.add(c);
    }

    for(int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS){
        colors.add(c);
    }

    for(int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS){
        colors.add(c);
    }

    for(int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS){
        colors.add(c);
    }

    for(int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS){
        colors.add(c);
    }

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

    pieDataSet.setColor(colors);
```

Please explain me why is this happening & how to solve.

Thank You.

Comment: `pieDataSet.setColors(colors);`, not `pieDataSet.setColor(colors);` (according to the duplicate question)

Answer (score 0):

`setColor` takes an int, what you want to invoke is `setColors` which takes an ArrayList of Integers [see Docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors)